# Undefined index in $_FILES

Tags: php, html, image, file, server

I am getting the error that my index is undefined in $_FILES. I am trying to copy a picture with php on my server.

Error:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: bilddatei in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aufgabe8.php on line 85
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: namefile in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aufgabe8.php on line 86
```

I've already tried with isset($_FILES["bilddatei"]) but this returns false too.

Code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['Datenbank']) and
    !isset($_SESSION['Kennung']) and !isset($_SESSION['Passwort']) )
{
    echo "<p>Bitte starten Sie zuerst mit der Eingabe-Startseite. Sie werden automatisch nach 5 Sekunden weitergeleitet.</p>";
    // automatisches Zurueckspringen nach 5 Sekunden nach 'index.html': 
    echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5;url=login.php">';
} else {
          echo "<form action=\"aufgabe8.php\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">
                    <p>Datei von PC hochladen
                        <input type=\"file\" name=\"bilddatei\" size\"60\" accept=\"image/*\"/>
                    </p>

                    <p><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Bild anzeigen\" name=\"bildBtn\"/></p>
                </form>";


    if(isset($_POST["bildBtn"])) {
            echo "<p>BILD IF</p>";

            $nameFile = $_FILES['bilddatei']['name'];
            echo "<p>$namefile</p>";

            //copy($fileSource,$destination); 

    }
```

Do you have any ideas? Thanks! :-)

Comment: Is this a typo that your else is not closed?

Comment: just because you echo the form, doesn't mean it's submitted.  the code is confusing as to weather you think this or the form is displayed on submission.

Comment: Nope the else is closed I've just copied the relevant code

Answer (score 2):

Variable name is different. Both php variable is `case-sensitive`.check `$nameFile` <=> `$namefile`.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_variables.asp

```
$namefile = $_FILES['bilddatei']['name'];
echo "<p>$namefile</p>";
```

Comment: you have to take care about variable definition.

Answer (score 1):

I think these things need to be done separately instead...

Render form

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['Datenbank']) and
    !isset($_SESSION['Kennung']) and !isset($_SESSION['Passwort']) )
{
    echo "<p>Bitte starten Sie zuerst mit der Eingabe-Startseite. Sie werden automatisch nach 5 Sekunden weitergeleitet.</p>";
    // automatisches Zurueckspringen nach 5 Sekunden nach 'index.html': 
    echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5;url=login.php">';
} else {
    echo "<form action=\"aufgabe8.php\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">
            <p>Datei von PC hochladen
                <input type=\"file\" name=\"bilddatei\" size\"60\" accept=\"image/*\"/>
            </p>

            <p><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Bild anzeigen\" name=\"bildBtn\"/></p>
        </form>";
}  ///missing } close I am assuming it goes here
```

Second php file ( say aufgabe8.php to match the form action )

```
if(isset($_POST["bildBtn"])) {
    echo "<p>BILD IF</p>";

    $nameFile = $_FILES['bilddatei']['name'];
    echo "<p>$nameFile</p>";  //spelling  $nameFile is not $namefile

    //copy($fileSource,$destination); 

}
```

Just because you echo out the form is very different then when it's submitted.  The code is confusing on whether or not you understand this.  In any case they are 2 distinct actions.

Besides the spelling mistakes as mentioned in the other answer.

Now you can do them in the same page like this

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['Datenbank']) and
    !isset($_SESSION['Kennung']) and !isset($_SESSION['Passwort']) )
{
    echo "<p>Bitte starten Sie zuerst mit der Eingabe-Startseite. Sie werden automatisch nach 5 Sekunden weitergeleitet.</p>";
    // automatisches Zurueckspringen nach 5 Sekunden nach 'index.html': 
    echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5;url=login.php">';
} else {

    if(isset($_POST["bildBtn"])) {
        ///submitted so process it
        echo "<p>BILD IF</p>";

        $nameFile = $_FILES['bilddatei']['name'];
        echo "<p>$nameFile</p>";  //spelling  $nameFile is not $namefile

        //copy($fileSource,$destination); 
    }else{
        ///not submitted so rendor the form
        echo "<form action=\"aufgabe8.php\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">
            <p>Datei von PC hochladen
                <input type=\"file\" name=\"bilddatei\" size\"60\" accept=\"image/*\"/>
            </p>

            <p><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Bild anzeigen\" name=\"bildBtn\"/></p>
        </form>";

    }
}
```

You can even render the form, and process it in the same block  ( without the `else` ), but just rendering it doesn't mean someone submitted it. In this case I would do away with the echo and just us plain old html to output the form.

Comment: So you mean I have to do it in two separate files? Because normally I do everything in one file and check if a button is clicked or a variable is set with isset.

Comment: Technically, you can do it in the same file, but just echoing the form, is not the same as submitting it.   Echoing it out, is a sever operation, and submitting it is something the client does.

Comment: In other words, you can output the form, but until a user submits it you can't process the data in it, right.  With that missing `}` its hard to tell if you were making that mistake or not.   For ease of coding and readabillity, it's often better to handle them separately, then you can avoid having a condition to either render or process.